# change control from different page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

page1

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="text1"/>
```

page2

when page2 Load in This Method

```
protected void btna_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     text1.text="test";
}
```

how change control in page1 from page2 method btna_Click1

or

HTML

```
 <input type="text" runat="server" id="text1"/>
```

Code

```
class test2
{
    public void changeText(control cnt)
    {
     cnt.text="test";
    }
}

protected void btna_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    test2 t=new test2();

     test2.changeText(text1)
}
```

I want the `test1` is on page1 in the modified method btna_Click1 on page 2

Comment: are the two pages displayed at the same time? Or does page2 redirect to page1 ?  A little more info please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your situation I weel be use Query Strings [More info here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring)

Your page object have life cycle between Begin Request and End Requests
  Begin Request -> Create PageObject -> do all events (function in page and control) -> Rendering Html -> destroy pageObject -> End Request

You may keep util information (objects) on ViewState ([More info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)) or Session ([More info here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx)) for passing it between pages

Comment: i can use class test2 and call test2 in page1 for change text

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that Page has a property named "PreviousPage" ? :-)

Comment: what is this .  description more

Comment: PreviousPage property returns a page that was visited before this page. More info can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx